# Even though logo is transparent and is of png type still in the website the logo is appearing with white background

Tags: html, css, background-image, transparent

`<img src="images/arch_bluev2.png" title="arch_blck logo" alt="arch_blck" width="80" height="80">`

[image: transparent image][image: white background]`

There must have not been white background. Instead it should have a transparent as the image itself is transparent and is of png type.

Comment: Code can't be explained by words - you have to show us your code **and** the image.

Comment: We can't help you without any code or a example showing your problem

Comment: If you are talking about the image in the question then no, its background is not transparent.

Comment: We need to see your actual arch_bluev2.png image as well as the code, and especially the CSS relevant to it.

Comment: The image you posted does have a checkered background

Comment: @AHaworth actually i have not created any specific css rule for the image, As i thought the image is transparent itselft so just by adding <img src> in html will be enough.

Comment: @NicoShultz aren't transparent images supposed to be checkered?

Comment: Your image does not have a transparent background, it has a checkered background - which may have made you feel it was transparent. I can see the chequered effect on your image with the black background now I zoom in enough. You need to find an image of the logo without the chequered background.

Comment: @AHaworth thanks. You guys were right its checkered background. Apparently google shows most of the result with checkered background instead of transparent.

Comment: @NicoShultz thanks man for pointing out the problem. I have also found this awesome site which provide transparent icons:  https://www.transparentpng.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is the same as the one you had uploaded in post, than the background is not really transparent. It just looks like. I quickly transform this to be transparent.[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: working_pn_logo]
[image: arch_logo]

The issue was with the logo background itself as it was not really transparent. After downloading genuine transparent png file, things went perfectly. Thanks everyone !!